# Is it right to always keep the first parameter of strtok_s as NULL?

Tags: c, strtok

I used to consider when the first time to call `strtok_s()` should pass the string containing token as the first parameter like following code:

```
char testString[100] = "1|2|3";
char *context = testString;
const char *token = strtok_s( testString, "|", &context );
while ( token )
    token = strtok_s( NULL, "|", &context );
```

However, I saw someone always keeps the first parameter as `NULL`, like following code:

```
char testString[100] = "1|2|3";
char *context = testString;
const char *token = strtok_s( NULL, "|", &context );
while ( token )
    token = strtok_s( NULL, "|", &context );
```

I know it works and how it works. Because `context` points to the same buffer as `testString`. But I feel a little bit weird and my doubt is:

1. Is it a good practice of using `strtok_s()`? What are the potential bugs it may face?
2. If this is a good practice, why `strtok_s()` still needs to keep the first parameter? It can be `NULL` as always, can't it?

Comment: The only guarantee I see is that the fourth parameter is used to store the internal state. The implementation could put anything it wanted there, but typically it's going to be where to pick up on the next call. In other words, someone could do something really interesting with that pointer, and then you're SOL.

Comment: Agreed.  The second version is in violation of the function's specification.  The code adds nothing in terms of readability either, so I don't see the point.  Also, let's imagine two completely conceivable implementations where the internal state assumes: (A) context points to the start of the next valid token, and tokenization is complete if that is `'\0'`; (B) context points to the last `'\0'` written and terminates when the _next_ character is `'\0'` or both `str` and `context` are NULL.  These implementations would result in different behavior for the offending usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the function [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), the correct usage of the function
is the first one you mentioned.

Further quoting from the C11 standard (emphasis mine), section K.3.7.3.1 (page 616):

> 3. A sequence of calls to the strtok_s function breaks the string pointed to by s1 into a
>      sequence of tokens, each of which is delimited by a character from the string pointed to
>      by s2. **The fourth argument points to a caller-provided char pointer into which the
>      strtok_s function stores information necessary for it to continue scanning the same
>      string**.
> 4. **The first call in a sequence has a non-null first argument** and s1max points to an object
>      whose value is the number of elements in the character array pointed to by the first
>      argument. The first call stores an initial value in the object pointed to by ptr and
>      updates the value pointed to by s1max to reflect the number of elements that remain in
>      relation to ptr. **Subsequent calls in the sequence have a null first argument and the
>      objects pointed to by s1max and ptr are required to have the values stored by the
>      previous call in the sequence, which are then updated**. The separator string pointed to by
>      s2 may be different from call to call.

Thus, what the standard says is that the correct usage is to call `strtok_s` with a non-NULL first argument, then call it with a NULL first argument. Upon the first call, the function initializes some state, and uses the provided pointer (the last argument) to store it.

The standard does not mention how the last argument should be used, rather than to hold the state such that the function can continue searching the same string when called with an *unmodified* pointer. Basically, it removes the need for the internal state of `strtok`, such that you can, for example, tokenize multiple strings at the same time.

The way the state space is used is thus *implementation defined*. It might well be the case that, on some implementations, it works to simply put there the initial string and always call it with the first argument NULL, as you have shown. But there is no guarantee that this happens on all implementations or that this behaviour will remain the same in the future versions of the library.

To directly answer your question, yes, it may work, but no, it is not a good idea to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is it a good practice of using `strtok_s()`?

No, it's bad practice.

Even if it happens to work (as it does here), it's bad *because* you're having to ask the question. You're asking the question because the code looks surprising, which means the author of this code has wasted your time by making it harder to understand than necessary.

> ... What are the potential bugs it may face?

- another C library might implement the function differently
- another developer might move or change the assignment to `context` because it's unusual to use it like this

> 2. If this is a good practice, why strtok_s() still needs to keep the first parameter?

Since it isn't good practice this question is moot, but it's worth pointing out another reason, related to the principle of least surprise to which your predecessor so conspicuously failed to adhere: *consistency*.

Consistent interfaces are less surprising, easier to reason about and easier to avoid messing up. This prototype retains consistency with other existing interfaces (although I see you're using the MS `strtok_s` rather than the standard C11 version) - if you remove the first argument the apparent ordering of the source string and delimiter arguments is reversed compared to the other `strtok` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think the second form is harmless. Because:

1. Many code has already be written in the second form. Changing the implementation will break them and cause unnecessary trouble.
2. There is no room for a better implementation.

I even use strtok_s() only once in the code:

```
char* context = testString;
// 1. with 'for' loop: 'token' will not leak into outer scope
for (const char* token; (token = strtok_s(NULL, "|", &context)) != NULL;)
    use(token);

// 2. with 'while' loop
char* context = testString;
const char* token2;
while((token2 = strtok_s(NULL, "|", &context)) != NULL)
    use(token);
```

Below is an implementation my team has be using.

```
char* my_strtok_s(char* buf, const char* splitters, char** context)
{
    char* p = *context;
    char* token;

    if (buf != NULL)
        p = buf;

    if (p == NULL) 
    {
        *context = p;
        return NULL;
    }

    while(strchr(splitters, *p) && *p != 0)
        p++;

    token = p;
    while(*p != 0)
    {
        if (strchr(splitters, *p))
        {
            *p = 0;
            p++;
            break;
        }
        p++;
    }

    *context = p;

    return *token != 0 ? token : NULL;
}
```